# g++ turn off constant propagation for benchmarking?

Tags: c++, g++

I want to run a simple benchmark of a function in C++ with a few function calls that use hard coded inputs.

```
inline Output simple_func_to_test(const Input input);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // The value of input is known at compile time.
    const Input input;
    // The value of output can be deduced at compile time.
    Output output = simple_func_to_test(input);
}
```

I don't have a detailed understanding of assembly but from inspecting the assembly generated using g++ 4.8 with Ofast it seems that the compiler is optimizing out the function and evaluating the value of output at compile time. For example, C++ functions that involve multiplication generate assembly that does no multiplication.

In the example above, I'd like to compile with all optimizations turned on except the value of input should be treated as if it were not known at compile time.

How can I change the C++ or pass a flag to g++ to do this?

On the gcc [optimization flags page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) there are a large number of flags related to constant propagation. The subtleties and exact meaning of all of these is lost on me.

EDIT: I have no interest in turning off constant propagation entirely. I just want input to be treated as if it were not known at compile time.

Comment: Mark `simple_func_to_test` with the attributes noinline and noclone.

Comment: You could also make `input` a `volatile` variable.

Comment: Why do you want to measure how long it takes for the compiler to do something that isn't it's best optimisation of your actual code? If you are multiplying constant values, then you the compiler will multiply at compile time. Someone probably spent hours (if not days or weeks) to make that optimisation work. Give your function some real data, and the compiler won't optimise it away (unless it's very simple still).

Comment: When you do an experiment such as a performance test, you have to scientifically accept the results. Redesign *the experiment* if you discover that you did not measure what was intended. Breaking the measurement tool to give fudged results is just wrong.

Comment: By the way, not that it's fundamentally impossible to have a compiler without constant propagation, but it is so fundamental that they made a decision (in common with other compilers) not to make a switch for it. (Interprocedural constant propagation notwithstanding, but if this function is actually inlined, it doesn't count as a separate procedure.)

Comment: I want to simulate the case in which input is not known at compile time. I don't necessarily want to interfere with the compiler.

Comment: @Praxeolitic Then simulate the kind of scenario that results in the compiler not knowing the value. It's not hard to do. Causing brain damage to the compiler cannot have a good outcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to simulate the case in which input is not known at compile time. I don't necessarily want to interfere with the compiler.

The simplest way to make the system uncertain of the value of a variable is to declare it `volatile`:

```
const volatile Input input;
```

Its value will be re-read from memory before the function call. The inside of the function will not be disturbed, making it otherwise a fully realistic simulation.